# Are Complements of Objects Considered 'Predicative' and 'Locative'?

Tags: direct-objects, predicative-complements, locatives

Subjects can take two types of complements: predicative (adjectives and nominals) and locative. Is this the same for objects?

Examples:

> He painted the town **red**.
>
> I kept the money **out of sight**.

Traditionally, we would call these 'object complements' (the latter possibly an adverbial complement). However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) says that the designation of 'predicative complement' applies to both subjects and objects. There isn't much detail to explain why. My understanding is that the predicate completes the subject, so I would be interested in a more complete analysis.

Comment: Are you only interested what they're' called?

Comment: In this framework, you can have a complement in the predicate (*predicative complement*), and it could complement either the subject or the object (*subjective predicative complement* or *objective predicative complement*).

Comment: @JohnLawler. Mostly, yes. And the reason as to why, as I always assumed 'predicative' related to the subject, not the object.

Comment: That depends on what linguistic theory you're using. "Predicative" relates to the predicate, naturally. In the theory I use, the verb phrase is the predicate, and specifically the verb, predicate adjective, or predicate noun (_be tired, be a doctor_) is the most important part of the predicate -- the predication. _Bill is tired_ predicates tiredness of Bill. As for "complements", I don't know what you mean by that word. I only use it to refer to noun clauses that function as subject or object. Other uses are handwaving, because it's not defined in terms of grammar tests.

Comment: @JohnLawler My definition of 'complement' is anything that is required to complete the meaning of the sentence, the opposite of an adjunct, which can be removed without major alteration. If we say that the predicate is the verb phrase, we could surmise that the object complement is a predicative complement, as it completes the meaning of a transitive verb. This is similar to a subject complement, which completes the meaning of a copular verb (intransitive).

Comment: How can you tell whether it "completes the meaning of the sentence"? That's hardly a grammatical test; this is what I meant by handwaving. I also don't use the terms "copular verb" (in English, at least), "adjunct", or "predicative complement", for the same reasons.

Comment: This is my biggest issue with trying to learn English grammar. You see these terms as useless, whereas other people advocate them. BillJ, another avid user of this forum, uses these terms often, and he is the person from whom I have adopted the terminology.